# How to find the distinct number of elements in data frame column, in which strings contain multiple elements separated by a semi-colon

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm importing some data from excel and trying to make a dashboard on streamlit. Right now, I'm trying to count the number of distinct elements in one of the columns of a data frame referred to as 'Tags'. However, for some of the rows, I have distinct values that are combined into a single string, rather than multiple strings.

With the first 'for loop' the data came out like this...
"Python; C++"
"Java; Python"
"R; C; Java"

Instead of like... [Python, C++, Java, R, C]. With the second 'for loop,' I'm attempting to do what I want, however, the program outputs nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
cnt=0
visited=[]
for i in range(0, len(df1['Tags'])):
    
    if df1['Tags'][i] not in visited: 
        
        visited.append(df1['Tags'][i])
          
        cnt += 1
u=[]
for j in range(0, len(visited)):
    new= visited[j].split(';')
    for z in range(0, len(new)):
        if new not in u:
            u.append(new)
st.write(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it result that you want?

```
list(set([j.strip() for i in df1["Tags"] for j in i.split(';')]))
```

Comment: No, this won't work. I keep getting an error about how a float cannot be split. However, that doesn't make sense because it's a string.